# How does this subtraction work in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, machine-learning

My question only regards a very small part of this code, but im posting it all incase it helps. It is taken from http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html#implementing_our_network_to_classify_digits (scroll down from here to see code explanations)

```
import numpy as np

    class Network(object):

    def __init__(self, sizes):
        """The list ``sizes`` contains the number of neurons in the
        respective layers of the network.  For example, if the list
        was [2, 3, 1] then it would be a three-layer network, with the
        first layer containing 2 neurons, the second layer 3 neurons,
        and the third layer 1 neuron.  The biases and weights for the
        network are initialized randomly, using a Gaussian
        distribution with mean 0, and variance 1.  Note that the first
        layer is assumed to be an input layer, and by convention we
        won't set any biases for those neurons, since biases are only
        ever used in computing the outputs from later layers."""
        self.num_layers = len(sizes)
        self.sizes = sizes
        self.biases = [np.random.randn(y, 1) for y in sizes[1:]]
        self.weights = [np.random.randn(y, x)
                        for x, y in zip(sizes[:-1], sizes[1:])]

    def feedforward(self, a):
        """Return the output of the network if ``a`` is input."""
        for b, w in zip(self.biases, self.weights):
            a = sigmoid(np.dot(w, a)+b)
        return a

    def SGD(self, training_data, epochs, mini_batch_size, eta,
            test_data=None):
        """Train the neural network using mini-batch stochastic
        gradient descent.  The ``training_data`` is a list of tuples
        ``(x, y)`` representing the training inputs and the desired
        outputs.  The other non-optional parameters are
        self-explanatory.  If ``test_data`` is provided then the
        network will be evaluated against the test data after each
        epoch, and partial progress printed out.  This is useful for
        tracking progress, but slows things down substantially."""
        if test_data: n_test = len(test_data)
        n = len(training_data)
        for j in xrange(epochs):
            random.shuffle(training_data)
            mini_batches = [
                training_data[k:k+mini_batch_size]
                for k in xrange(0, n, mini_batch_size)]
            for mini_batch in mini_batches:
                self.update_mini_batch(mini_batch, eta)
            if test_data:
                print "Epoch {0}: {1} / {2}".format(
                    j, self.evaluate(test_data), n_test)
            else:
                print "Epoch {0} complete".format(j)

    def update_mini_batch(self, mini_batch, eta):
        """Update the network's weights and biases by applying
        gradient descent using backpropagation to a single mini batch.
        The ``mini_batch`` is a list of tuples ``(x, y)``, and ``eta``
        is the learning rate."""
        nabla_b = [np.zeros(b.shape) for b in self.biases]
        nabla_w = [np.zeros(w.shape) for w in self.weights]
        for x, y in mini_batch:
            delta_nabla_b, delta_nabla_w = self.backprop(x, y)
            nabla_b = [nb+dnb for nb, dnb in zip(nabla_b, delta_nabla_b)]
            nabla_w = [nw+dnw for nw, dnw in zip(nabla_w, delta_nabla_w)]
        self.weights = [w-(eta/len(mini_batch))*nw
                        for w, nw in zip(self.weights, nabla_w)]
        self.biases = [b-(eta/len(mini_batch))*nb
                       for b, nb in zip(self.biases, nabla_b)]

    def backprop(self, x, y):
        """Return a tuple ``(nabla_b, nabla_w)`` representing the
        gradient for the cost function C_x.  ``nabla_b`` and
        ``nabla_w`` are layer-by-layer lists of numpy arrays, similar
        to ``self.biases`` and ``self.weights``."""
        nabla_b = [np.zeros(b.shape) for b in self.biases]
        nabla_w = [np.zeros(w.shape) for w in self.weights]
        # feedforward
        activation = x
        activations = [x] # list to store all the activations, layer by layer
        zs = [] # list to store all the z vectors, layer by layer
        for b, w in zip(self.biases, self.weights):
            z = np.dot(w, activation)+b
            zs.append(z)
            activation = sigmoid(z)
            activations.append(activation)
        # backward pass
        delta = self.cost_derivative(activations[-1], y) * \
            sigmoid_prime(zs[-1])
        nabla_b[-1] = delta
        nabla_w[-1] = np.dot(delta, activations[-2].transpose())
        # Note that the variable l in the loop below is used a little
        # differently to the notation in Chapter 2 of the book.  Here,
        # l = 1 means the last layer of neurons, l = 2 is the
        # second-last layer, and so on.  It's a renumbering of the
        # scheme in the book, used here to take advantage of the fact
        # that Python can use negative indices in lists.
        for l in xrange(2, self.num_layers):
            z = zs[-l]
            sp = sigmoid_prime(z)
            delta = np.dot(self.weights[-l+1].transpose(), delta) * sp
            nabla_b[-l] = delta
            nabla_w[-l] = np.dot(delta, activations[-l-1].transpose())
        return (nabla_b, nabla_w)

    def evaluate(self, test_data):
        """Return the number of test inputs for which the neural
        network outputs the correct result. Note that the neural
        network's output is assumed to be the index of whichever
        neuron in the final layer has the highest activation."""
        test_results = [(np.argmax(self.feedforward(x)), y)
                        for (x, y) in test_data]
        return sum(int(x == y) for (x, y) in test_results)

    def cost_derivative(self, output_activations, y):
        """Return the vector of partial derivatives \partial C_x /
        \partial a for the output activations."""
        return (output_activations-y)

#### Miscellaneous functions
def sigmoid(z):
    """The sigmoid function."""
    return 1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-z))

def sigmoid_prime(z):
    """Derivative of the sigmoid function."""
    return sigmoid(z)*(1-sigmoid(z))
```

Ignore most of the code unless you need to step back to understand the data structure. Firstly, in the line `self.cost_derivative(activations[-1], y)` half way down in the `backprop` method, we can see that two values are passed through - from what I can tell, both values are arrays (i can see this when outputting them, and it is also explained from the author). In the `cost_derivative` method, all it does is subtract the two values - but they are arrays, so how does this work?

when i do this in python i understandably get an error

```
a = [1,2,4]
b = [5,6,7]
print(a-b)
```

I believe it could be to with the fact they are numpy arrays?

Also, a similar thing is happening with the `sigmoid` and `sigmoid_prime` functions, where `z` is an array (see where these functions are called with the argument as an array)...even though the function treats it as if it was a single value...how does that work? I assume it just does it to each value within the array?

Essentially, I keep seeing functionality that i would expect only works with single values to be working with arrays.

Cheers for any explanation, and the link i posted has a little more explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that the subtraction works because `output_activations` and `y` are numpy arrays. [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) is a python library for fast matrix operations, and numpy arrays overload `-` to perform matrix subtraction.

However, in your example, `[1,2,4]` is just a plain python list, not a numpy array, and the `-` operator isn't defined for lists. If you replace your lists with numpy arrays, your output makes more sense:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,4])
b = np.array([5,6,7])
print(a-b)
# [-4 -4 -3]
```

Comment: makes sense. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

When you subtract two lists:

```
a = [1,2,4]
b = [5,6,7]
print(a-b)
```

python calls a function `__sub__` that tries to subtract them.  Vanilla python's `__sub__` can't subtract lists, and list objects don't have `__sub__` functions, so it throws an error.

When you subtract a list from a numpy array:

```
a = [1,2,4]
b = numpy.array([5,6,7])
print(a-b)
```

Vanilla `__sub__` still fails, but python looks for any object-specific `__sub__` functions and finds numpy's.  Numpy wraps all other objects in `np.asarray()` and tries to subtract them like numpy arrays.  Since a list is mapped to a 1D array, and the sizes are the same, the subtraction works and you end up with an array as output.

Comment: Yes, in python you can overload the `-` operator by defining `__sub__` on an object, but I'm not aware of a `__sub__` builtin function in python. When you write `a-b`, python tries to call `a.__sub__(b)`. There's no such thing as 'Vanilla `__sub__`'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are getting the error, because those are numpy arrays and not scalars.
Use np.subtract(a, b) instead.You need to remember that you are trying to subtract vectors.

Comment: How come in the code, they do not even use np.substract, but just the - ?

Comment: I'm guessing it might be due to the fact that he is declaring just plain python list

Comment: Hold on - isnt that exactly what i am doing in my failed example? Cheers for the help.

Comment: Ahh.... sorry I'm getting tired , yes that's a little bit odd.I'll test it tomorrow and see if I'm getting the same error.

Comment: No worries! the other answer just posted explains it spot on if you still wondering. Thanks anyway.